# Nilpotent matrix in $3$ dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a part of a long problem and I'm stuck in two questions of it.

Let $E$ a $3$ dimensional $\mathbb R$- vector space and $g\in\mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $g^3=0$. So the first question is to prove that
$$\dim\left(\ker g\cap \mathrm{Im}\ g\right)\leq 1$$
and the second is: assume that $g^2\ne 0$, prove that if $\ker g=\ker g^2$ then $E=\ker g\oplus \mathrm{Im}\ g$ and deduce a contradiction, hence determinate $\dim\ker g$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint : $\;\;\;$ For the first question, you don't actually need to use that $\:\: g^3 = 0 \;\;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Ah ok for the first question I should use the rank nullity theorem.

Comment: I don't immediately see how to do the second question. $\;$

Comment: Curious to know how you went with this problem. I'm new to the site and as a tutor, feedback helps me just as much as the people for whom I answer questions. Cheers.

Comment: I'm also curious to know if anyone has a briefer solution than mine. I didn't use the contradiction suggested in the hint for the question which might involve showing the intersection by the first part had dimension zero hence the mention of $E = \ker g \oplus$ im $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part dim(im$\,g$)$ + $ dim $(\ker\,g) = 3$.

The possible combinations are $0 + 3$, $1 + 2$, $2 + 1$, $3 + 0$ and you can see that any intersection cannot have dimension greater than 1.

For the second part:

\begin{align*}
g^3(x) &= 0,\, \forall x \in E \\
g^2(g(x)) &= 0 ,\, \forall x \in E \\
&\Rightarrow \text{ im } g \subset \ker g^2 - (1)
\end{align*}

Assume $\ker g = \ker g^2$ then

\begin{align*}
(1) &\Rightarrow \text{ im } g \subset \ker g \\
&\Rightarrow g(g(x)) = 0,\, \forall x \in E \\
&\Rightarrow g^2 = 0
\end{align*}

This is a contradiction as $g^2 \neq 0 - (2)$

\begin{align*}
g^2(x) &= g(g(x)) = 0,\, \forall x \in \ker g \\
&\Rightarrow \ker g \subset \ker g^2 \\
&\Rightarrow \dim (\ker g) \leq \dim (\ker g^2) \\
(2) &\Rightarrow \dim (\ker g) < \dim (\ker g^2) - (3)
\end{align*}

Clearly, as $g^2 \neq 0$, we have with (1) and (3):

\begin{align*}
1 &\leq \dim (\ker g) < \dim (\ker g^2) \leq 2 \\
&\Rightarrow \dim (\ker g) = 1
\end{align*}

Addendum 1: Sometimes playing with an example helps to see what's going on. Find the kernel and image of $A$ and $A^2$ in the following example in $\mathbb R^3$.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$